# breadcrumb need to show all pages and subpages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, breadcrumb

am using Breadcrumb NavXT plugin.

i want to show all the pages and subpages in breadcrumb.i know this is tough to understand, so am explain briefly here.

---

i have the pages:

->mainpage

--->subpage1

--->subpage2

--->subpage3

if i select **main page** it need to show 
**you are here>subpage1>subpage2>subpage3**

if i select **subpage3** it need to show
**mainpage>subpage1>subpage2>you are here**

if i select **subpage1** it need to show
**subpage2>subpage3>mainpage>you are here**

i guess,now you got my question.breadcrumb need to show circularly with all pages.
please help me to achieve this. any plugin do this? or any code?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not traditionally how breadcrumb navigation works, as I'm guessing you've discovered if you're trying to implement Breadcrumb NavXT. :) You might have better luck styling [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) so the links display horizontally and highlight the page you're on? Here's where it describes how to display the [current page / ancestors / children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_current_Page.2C_ancestors_of_current_page.2C_and_children_of_current_page).

Best of luck!